# Копирующая инициализация

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11

```
class A {
    int _x;
public:
    A(int x) : _x(x) {}

};

int main()
{
    A s = 2; // вот она
}
```

Я не понимаю как это работает? Так как копирующая инициализация инициализирует объект из другого объекта, компилятор видит литерал int и приводит к типу A, то есть в теории должен вызваться конструктор для создания анонимного объекта, что бы потом вызвать конструктор копирования и инициализировать объект s анонимным объектом? Получается что это будет выглядеть так: A s = A(2);?

На практике компилятор это все оптимизирует будет вызван один конструктор. Получается если ход мыслей верный, то по этой причине копирующая инициализация носит такое название?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> должен вызваться конструктор для создания анонимного объекта, что бы потом вызвать конструктор копирования

До С++17 [так и происходит](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init#17.6.2). И непонятно, почему стандарт не требует вызывать сразу правильный конструктор, без копирования.

Но:

- Тут перемещение, а не копирование.
- Не `A s = A(2);`, а `A s(A(2));`. Это проверяется деланием перемещающего (или копирующего, если перемещающего нет) конструктора `explicit`.
- Любой нормальный компилятор соптимизирует перемещение. От него остается только требование наличия перемещающего (или копирующего) конструктора, но и это требование исчезает в С++17.
- Начиная С++17, все это неважно, потому что компилятор обязан выбросить перемещение, не проверяя наличие перемещающего (или копирующего) конструктора. Поэтому `A s = 2;` превращается просто в `A s(2);`, с единственной разницей, что конструктор от int-а не может быть `explicit`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ничего страшного. :Р

Comment: В чем разница `Не A s = A(2);, а A s(A(2));.` (в этом контексте)? Я понимаю что первое - прямая, второе - копирующая. Прямая ведь напрямую вызывает конструктор, а копирующая проверяет подходят ли типы инициализатора и значения, а здесь типы подходят. Так в чем разница?

Comment: @Kurr200 В следующем предложении написано, в чем разница. *"первое - прямая, второе - копирующая"* Наоборот. *"копирующая проверяет подходят ли типы"* Ммм? В каком смысле проверяет? Они обе проверяют тип аргумента, как без этого?

Comment: Прямая инициализация напрямую вызывает конструктор и уже к параметрам конструктора производит неявное преобразование аргументов , а копирующая при такой вот записи `A s = 2;` сначала должна `2` преобразовать к типу `A`, с помощью конструктора (который не является explicit) и уже потом вызвать конструктор перемещения для инициализации объекта `s`. На практике вы уже написали это все оптимизируется.